# Determine the integrity of a string - PHP

Tags: php

Why are str_rot13() and crypt() inefficient ways to determine the integrity of a string compared to crc32() ? ( according to some zend examination tests )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str_rot13 doesn't hash the string, it's effectively a copy. This is redundant data and is a waste.

crypt() takes a lot of CPU, and is also a copy.

But crc32() generates a hash of the data, only 32 bits long. And the chances of a corrupted string having the same hash as the pristine data, is one in a zillion.